# Slideshow in ASP>NET MVC 5

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I followed the w3school.com's slideshow tutorial ( https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp ) for my asp.net mvc 5 application. The problem I am having is that when I launch the application. The slides show and then fade away very fast and the picture never stays. I think I have narrowed down the problem to the css, but I cannot figure out why the pictures show and then fade quickly and never come back. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

I have tried commenting out various parts of the css and changing some values but none have solved the problem. I debugged the javascript and it seems fine. The index also does not seem to be causing any problems. My only thought is that it must be the css.

Javascript:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

    if (n > slides.length)
    {
        slideIndex = 1
    }

    if (n < 1)
    {
        slideIndex = slides.length
    }

    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++)
    {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++)
    {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;

}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Override the default bootstrap behavior where horizontal description lists 
   will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column 
*/
.dl-horizontal dt {
    white-space: normal;
}

/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}

/* Fixed footer. */
footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #222;
    color: #9d9d9d;
}

body .bodyDiv {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Impact, Times New Roman, Times, serif;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: #222;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px #9d9d9d;
}

/* SlideShow Css. */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default 
.mySlides {
    display: none;
}*/

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

    /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
    .prev:hover, .next:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }

/* Caption text */
.text {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

    .active, .dot:hover {
        background-color: #717171;
    }

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}
```

Index View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/SlideShow")
<!-- SlideShow. -->
<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">

    <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>

        <img src="~/Content/Patern_test.jpg" style="width:100%">

        <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
        <img src="~/Content/Patern_test.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="~/Content/Patern_test.jpg">3 / 3</div>
        <img src="~/Content/Patern_test.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>

<body>
    <div class="bodyDiv">
        Welcome To KrugDevelopment
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're putting your html elements outside the body tag, however, this problem has something to do with the opacity and animation, so :

SOLUTION 1 : 
try to add this to your CSS :

```
.mySlides {
      opacity:0;
}
```

SOLUTION 2 :
try to hide the slides when the page load

```
 .mySlides {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply however neither suggestion seemed to work. Sorry it took me so long to get try it. The display: none makes them disappear completely.